# Why isn't my ILoadEventListener being called?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I made a class that implements `ILoadEventListener`, and implemented an `OnLoad()` method (of course -- else it wouldn't even compile).  After creating the "new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()", I add it [as the documentation says](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events):

```
configuration.EventListeners.LoadEventListeners = new ILoadEventListener[] {
    new MyListener(),
    new NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener()
};
```

However, it never seems to get called -- I've added logging statements to my OnLoad() and set a breakpoint there in the debugger -- even when using my app in a way that clearly gets objects from the database using this NHibernate session factory.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I poked around in the source code (the NHibernate event documentation is rather sparse), and found that the event that corresponds to IInterceptor is actually PreLoad, not Load, so I tried using that, and that one does fire.  So I can use that for now, but I still don't really know what preload/load/postload are intended to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation on this is practically nonexistent, so maybe this will help a few people:

**None of the Load events (Load/PreLoad/PostLoad) will ever fire on an entity that is in the identity cache, even if you `Get`, `Load`, or query for it again.**

This *sort of* makes sense if you squint at it just the right way, but it makes for a great deal of frustration due to non-deterministic behaviour, since most of the time, you won't *know* whether or not an entity is in the cache. Evidently, these events refer to the process of *hydrating* an entity as opposed to simply *requesting* it.

I haven't tested this theory, but I wouldn't be surprised if cache hits from the L2 cache *also* don't fire Load events, since those entities won't be hydrated either.

In practice, this means that if you want a particular listener to run on "every" entity, you need to account for the possibility that it was originally a transient instance which was introduced to the session by `Save`, `Update`, etc. In other words, if you implement `IPostLoadEventListener`, you probably also want to implement `IPostInsertEventListener` and `IPostUpdateEventListener`.

This won't actually change the behaviour - the listener will still only ever run the very *first* time an entity becomes associated with the session - but at least this guarantees that every entity you can retrieve from the session has been intercepted by that listener. In my case, I was trying to use `PostLoad` to inject something into the entity, so this was an acceptable workaround.

If you really need the listener to fire *every* time an entity is retrieved, you either need to use a stateless session (no cache) or evict the entities before loading/querying again.